# Difference between Paths.get(""), Paths.get(".") and new File(".")

Tags: java

Is there any situation where `Paths.get("")`, `Paths.get(".")` and `new File(".").toPath()` could have different results?

Comment: Technically, `Paths.get("")` gives you a different result than `Paths.get(".")` - the latter includes a `.`, which means you are resolving the same directory through an extra link. It may not be a significant difference, but it is one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Paths.get("")` gives a path representing an empty path and `Paths.get("").toString()` returns the empty string.

`Paths.get(".")` gives a path representing the current directory and `Paths.get(".").toString()`  gives the string `"."`

So if you are generating string representation of paths `Paths.get("")` and `Paths.get(".")` **lead to different results**.